# Understanding move semantics for enums Rust

Tags: rust, move

So I'm looking at the impl for `is_some()` for `Option` and I noticed that it uses `match *self {}` under the hood...so it moves it internally.

My question is, if it gets moved, how am I able to do something like this? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f094da12290b77bad526674467e51043

```
fn main() {
    let x = Option::Some(3);
    x.is_some();
    x.is_some();
}
```

My expectation is that I should be able to  call `is_some()` only once, and the next time I call it I should get some sort of error saying it's been moved...but no, it all compiles fine.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Does is_some take self by value?

Comment: Another thing to consider is that there is a `impl<T> Copy for Option<T> where T: Copy` and the integer primitives are all `Copy`. Therefore, `Option<{integer}>` is also `Copy`.

Answer (score 5):

`*self` in `match *self { ... }` does not move (or copy) what `self` points to. From "[The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html)" (emphasis mine),

> A `match` behaves differently depending on whether or not the scrutinee expression is a place expression or value expression. **If the scrutinee expression is a value expression, it is first evaluated into a temporary location,** ...
>
> **When the scrutinee expression is a place expression, the match does not allocate a temporary location;** however, a by-value binding may copy or move from the memory location. ...

`*self` is a place expression. From "[The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions)" (emphasis mine),

> Expressions are divided into two main categories: place expressions and value expressions. ...
>
> **A *place expression* is an expression that represents a memory location.** These expressions are paths which refer to local variables, static variables, **dereferences (`*expr`)**, array indexing expressions (`expr[expr]`), field references (`expr.f`) and parenthesized place expressions. All other expressions are value expressions.
>
> A *value expression* is an expression that represents an actual value.

---

You might also be interested to know that the `Some(_) => true` arm in the `match` body does not bind anything. From "[The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#wildcard-pattern)",

> Unlike identifier patterns, it does not copy, move or borrow the value it matches.

where "it" means the wildcard pattern (`_`).

Answer (score 4):

(See the @dkim's answer for a more official and cited answer)

If the signature of the function accepts by reference, it does not take ownership of the value. Option.is_some() actually takes &self not self.

The interesting part is how `*self` is allowed to be used in a function that receives `&self` when `Self: Copy` is not bounded.

To test this, let's create a minimal example containing something similar: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7b137b74b5cd8f8bb57398ae01bf4e3

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum A {
    X(String),
    Y(i32),
}
pub fn f(a: &A) {
    match *a {
        A::X(_) => {
            //  dbg!(s);
        }
        A::Y(_i) => {
            //  dbg!(i);
        }
    };
}
```

This compiles fine. But let's change the `A::X(_)` pattern to `A::X(_s)`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93030e5c3f84532532c5db966c798bd6

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum A {
    X(String),
    Y(i32),
}
pub fn f(a: &A) {
    match *a {
        A::X(_s) => {
            //  dbg!(s);
        }
        A::Y(_i) => {
            //  dbg!(i);
        }
    };
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `a.0` which is behind a shared reference
 --> src/lib.rs:7:11
  |
7 |     match *a {
  |           ^^ help: consider borrowing here: `&*a`
8 |         A::X(_s) => {
  |              --
  |              |
  |              data moved here
  |              move occurs because `_s` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

So it appears that dereferencing a non-Copy enum is perfectly fine, as long as it wouldn't be used for moving inner non-Copy values. `_` is fine because it guarantees that the underlying value would never be used, while `_s` does not compile because it is just a normal allow(unused) variable.

This also makes sense because it allows the same match arm to work on both Copy and non-Copy types, as long as no usages violate the ownership rules